# Prediction Intervals for Incremental OLS regression

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, prediction-interval, online-algorithms

I am implementing incremental OLS regression algorithm where the data points arrive one at a time. As the regression parameters are determined by the formula, $(X'X)^{-1} X'y$ and the Sherman-Morrison formula provides a way to invert rank-1 updated $X'X$ matrix, it is possible to incorporate new data points and their corresponding responses into the OLS model in an online fashion.

However, I also need prediction intervals when I want to make a prediction given a data point $x$. The formula of prediction intervals for OLS regression includes the mean squared error of residuals, $s^2$, the problem here is that as the new data points come in regression parameters will change so the past residuals will be different so after each update of $X'X^{-1}$, I need to compute all the past residuals from scratch in order to come up with a prediction intervals for the $k$th data point (Note that the regression parameters has just been adjusted with $(k-1)$th data point).

My question is: Is there a way to update residuals as the regression parameters change automatically to compute running $s^2$?